# How to show lines without any modification

Tags: bash

I'm trying to show lines in a file without any modification, but line remove initial spaces/tabs, and I can't avoid.

My case:
I have "iptables -L -v" output file...

```
...
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 22641 packets, 2686K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
20143   11M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           
0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED  3648  148K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 ...
```

and I'm trying show line to line...

```
    ...
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 22641 packets, 2686K bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    20143   11M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3648  148K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    ...
```

Initial spaces are removed (I dont know if you can view it), when I show line to line with these commands:

```
for L in `cat FILE` | while read L; do echo "$L";done
```

or

```
for L in `cat FILE` | while read L; do printf "%s\n" "$L";done
```

In this case, the output of "iptables -L" command, show left columns aligned by right, and right columns aligned by left, getting a nice effect, and I want show line to line (I colour some lines, for example), with identical format, but lines is showing aligned by left always.

Do you know why, and how to solve it?

Comment: Surely it's flattening out every word into its own line? Is that the actual code you're running?

Comment: Sorry, is 'cat file | while read L; do...

Answer (score 2):

```
for L in `cat FILE` | while read L; do echo "$L";done
```

I highly doubt this is what you're running.The `for` loop isn't complete, and you should get a syntax error. Running the command in command substitution inside the word list of `for` (as in `for L in $(cat foo); do...`) would split all words on separate lines (and subject them to filename globbing).

However, something like

```
iptables -vL | while read L; do echo "$L"; done
```

would give about the output you get: `read` splits the input on `IFS` and as a side effect destroys leading and trailing whitespace. Give it an empty `IFS` to get what you want. Also, using `read -r` is highly recommended to disable processing of backslashes, even though `iptables` output isn't likely to have them. So:

```
iptables -vL | while IFS= read -r L; do echo "$L"; done
```

Or from a file, without `cat`:

```
while IFS= read -r L; do echo "$L"; done < file
```

If your goal is to modify the input lines in some way, you might also want to take a look at awk or Perl to do it, instead of the shell.

Comment: Exactly right. I'd also mention that if the last line doesn't end with newline, it may be truncated, and will be necessary to be echoed one more time after the loop is done. Also maybe printf would be nice addition, but that's just a personal preference probably

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake. The output of "iptables -vL" command is in "file", and I display line to line, but the problem is what I tell you...